# Issue with nth child height property

Tags: jquery, html, css

This Is my CSS Code.

```
    .filteredDocContent {
      display: none;
    }
    .filteredDocContent .photography:nth-child(1),
    .filteredDocContent .photography:nth-child(2),
    .filteredDocContent .photography:nth-child(3),
    .filteredDocContent .photography:nth-child(4),
    .filteredDocContent .photography:nth-child(5),
    .filteredDocContent .photography:nth-child(6),
    .filteredDocContent .photography:nth-child(7),
    .filteredDocContent .photography:nth-child(8) {
      display: block;
    }
```

What I do here -

Total 15 documents or more than(It will come according user insert or upload the data) are there and initially show only 1st 8 documents. But it take height of all documents and than button of load more appear.

This is my div When documents are display:-

```
<div id="lightbox" class="row filteredDocContent">
    <?php foreach ( $aDoc as $oDoc ) { ?>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 photography app" id="load_data">
        <div class="portfolio-item" style="margin-top:-12px;">
            <!-- <div class="hover-bg"> -->
            <div class="">
                <?php $sDocName=$ oDoc[ 'docPath']; ?>
                <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>front/home/downloadFile/?name=<?php echo $sDocName; ?>">
                <div class="hover-text" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="<?php echo $oDoc[ 'docSubject' ];?>">
                    <h4>  <?php echo substr($oDoc[ 'docSubject' ],0,20);?> </h4>
                </div>    
                <?php
                if( ! empty( $oDoc[ 'docThumb' ] ) )
                {
                    $thumbName = $oDoc[ 'docThumb' ];
                }
                else
                {
                    $thumbName = "assets/processedInfo/common.jpg";
                }
                ?>
                <img style="height:188px;width : 263px"
                src="<?php echo base_url () . $thumbName ?>" class="docThumb img-responsive"
                alt="<?php echo $oDoc[ 'docSubject' ];?>">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div>Uploaded By : <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="<?php echo $oDoc[ 'userName' ];?>"> <?php echo substr($oDoc[ 'userName' ],0,20);?> </span>
            </div>
            <div>HQ : <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="<?php echo @$oDoc[ 'hq' ];?>">  <?php echo substr(@$oDoc[ 'hq' ],0,20);?> </span>
            </div>
            <div>Subject : <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="<?php echo $oDoc[ 'docSubject' ];?>">  <?php echo substr($oDoc[ 'docSubject' ],0,20);?> </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
<?php if(count($aDoc)>8){ ?>
<button id="show_All" class="btn tf-btn btn-default pull-right">Load More</button>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

This is my code of on Load more Button click

```
$('#show_All').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.filteredDocContent .photography').filter(':hidden').show();
    $('#show_All').hide();
});
```

Comment: I think you should use  `display: inline-block;`

Comment: No It's Not Working. Still It display after all documents data. Initially 8 doc. Show and rest of are hide. After it show button of load more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your first rule on `.filteredDocContent` to apply to it's children, and not itself:

```
.filteredDocContent .photography{
     display: none;
}
```

Doing as the above, you are first making sure that *none* of the `.photography` elements are rendered as blocks, hence not occupying any space within their parent.

[***JSFiddle Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/baktash93/teh7mmxn/2/)

Comment: It will take the height between 1st row and 2nd row

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get you

Comment: I will give you the code when the document data are show. In that format the data is show